# Moran's I statistical significance with spdep mc.moran function

Tags: raster, autocorrelation, spdep

I would like to obtain Moran's I estimation together with its p-value from a raster data layer --which has na value-- including a figure showing the simulation distribution by mean of spdep::mc.moran() function.

I would like to know whether the code bellow implies the right manner to convert the rater to polygon as required to be input to the function spdep::mc.moran(), as well as whether the code bellow is an appropriate manner to alternatively solve the problem ?

```
library(raster)
library(spdep)

r<- raster(file.choose())
l <- rasterToPolygons(r)

nb.l <- poly2nb(l, queen=FALSE)
lw.l <- nb2listw(nb.l, style="W",zero.policy=TRUE)

v<-r[!is.na(r)]
M <- moran.mc((v), lw.l, 999, zero.policy=TRUE)
M
  
plot(M, main=sprintf("Original, Moran's I (p = %0.3f)", M$p.value), xlab="Monte-Carlo Simulation of Moran I", sub =NA, cex.lab=1.5, cex.axis=1.5, cex.main=1.5, cex.sub=1.5)
abline(v=M$statistic, col="red", lw=2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks perfectly correct to me - you can reproduce the value of `Moran(r)` if you use `queen=TRUE` in the neighbour calculation and use `style="B"` in the weighted neighbour calculation, so that all the weights are 1. With `style="W"` the sum of weights is 1 for each feature.

By default `raster::Moran` uses a weight matrix:

```
 w = matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), 3, 3)
```

which corresponds to queen's adjacency and a binary adjacency. Using my standard `r = raster(matrix(1:12, 4,3))` quick test raster, and following your code:

```
> nb.l <- poly2nb(l, queen=TRUE)
> lw.l <- nb2listw(nb.l, style="B",zero.policy=TRUE)
> v<-r[!is.na(r)]
> M <- moran.mc((v), lw.l, 999, zero.policy=TRUE)
> M

    Monte-Carlo simulation of Moran I

data:  (v) 
weights: lw.l  
number of simulations + 1: 1000 

statistic = 0.33205, observed rank = 994, p-value = 0.006
alternative hypothesis: greater

> Moran(r)
[1] 0.3320473
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Results now improved a lot.